# Solving a system of equations by substitution

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve the following system of equations by substitution
$$x + abs(y + 1) = 1$$
$$y + abs(z + 2) = 1$$
$$z + abs(x - 2) = 1$$

My idea was to simplify this system by substituting
$u = x – 2, v = y + 1;, w = z + 2$.

leading to
$$u + abs(v) = -1$$
$$v + abs(w) = 2$$
$$w + abs(u) = 3$$

Here I got stuck. Do I have to consider all eight combinations where $u$, $v$, or $w$ are greater or smaller than zero?

Comment: Since $u=-1-|v|$ you know $u<0$ so that cuts it down to four combinations.  Haven't considered whether this idea will go any further.

Comment: Based on David's comment, divide the analysis into 4 cases, and manually examine each case.

Answer (score 2):

David's tip was perfect, three of the four combinations were trivial. My answer is $-3 \leq u \leq -1, v = -(u + 1), w = u + 3$.